# JavaFX Dragging Undecorated Stage "Fallthrough" Problem

Tags: javafx, kotlin

I have an undecorated stage, with a custom titlebar in it. This titlebar contains "IconButtons", which are just StackPanes holding ImageViews.

I also use this code to make the stage draggable via the titlebar (Kotlin code):

```
fun makeDraggable(stage: Stage, byNode: Node) {

    val dragDelta = Delta()

    byNode.setOnMousePressed { e ->
        if (stage.isFullScreen || stage.isMaximized) {
            return@setOnMousePressed
        }

        dragDelta.x = stage.x - e.screenX
        dragDelta.y = stage.y - e.screenY
    }

    byNode.setOnMouseDragged { e ->
        if (stage.isFullScreen || stage.isMaximized) {
            return@setOnMouseDragged
        }

        stage.x = e.screenX + dragDelta.x
        stage.y = e.screenY + dragDelta.y
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the stage is draggable even when the mouse is over one of these "IconButtons". With normal JavaFX Buttons this does not seem be a problem. I'm failing to see why this is the case, and how to fix it.

Comment: Assuming the events work the same way as in java, you should be able to consume the events for the buttons or check the event's `pickResult` is one of the `Button`s or one of their descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the pickResult appears to work just fine (thanks fabian):

```
fun makeDraggable(stage: Stage, byNode: Node) {

    val dragDelta = Delta()

    var validTarget = true

    byNode.setOnMousePressed { e ->
        if (stage.isFullScreen || stage.isMaximized) {
            return@setOnMousePressed
        }

        val pickedNode = e.pickResult.intersectedNode

        if (pickedNode is IconButton) {
            validTarget = false
            return@setOnMousePressed
        }
        if (pickedNode.parent is IconButton) {
            validTarget = false
            return@setOnMousePressed
        }

        dragDelta.x = stage.x - e.screenX
        dragDelta.y = stage.y - e.screenY
    }

    byNode.setOnMouseReleased { e ->
        if (stage.isFullScreen || stage.isMaximized) {
            return@setOnMouseReleased
        }
        validTarget = true
    }

    byNode.setOnMouseDragged { e ->
        if (stage.isFullScreen || stage.isMaximized) {
            return@setOnMouseDragged
        }

        if (!validTarget) {
            return@setOnMouseDragged
        }

        stage.x = e.screenX + dragDelta.x
        stage.y = e.screenY + dragDelta.y
    }
}
```